# Replaying sound in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, audio, reset

I have a button that plays a 5 second clip of a song with a roll over mouse event. I want it to continue playing the song every time you roll over it but I can't figure out how to get the sound to loop. 
Here's my code so far:

```
var songOne:Song1 = new Song1();
var SongOneChannel:SoundChannel;
var soundPlaying:Boolean=false;

 stop();
btnOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,playSongOneFunction);
function playSongOneFunction(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
if(soundPlaying==false)
{
    SongOneChannel = songOne.play();
    trace("Did the Sound just start playing?");
    soundPlaying=true;
}
 }
```

Comment: What should happen if one would roll over the button faster than once in 5 seconds?

Comment: Is the only problem the you cannot loop the sound ? When someone rolls off the button, should it stop playing ? When you roll over it the next time, should it resume playing from where it left off ? You need to give more detail or you possibly aren't going to get the answer you desire. (and you'll waste people's time)

Comment: What I need to happen is that every time someone rolls over the button the song plays but only if its stopped. I don't want it to play over itself but I need it to replay if someone rolls over the button and it has stopped playing

Answer (score 0):

Just add listener to SongOneChannel SoundComplete. And renew sound playing in listener function.

Answer (score 0):

`soundPlaying` never gets reset to `false`, so the next time you roll over your button, it won't enter the if statement.

Either do as @Dub4ek suggests and add an `soundComplete` event so you can reset `soundPlaying`, or get rid of the check entirely, as you don't really need it - each time you call `songOne.play()`, a new `SoundChannel` is generated, so you can play the sound over itself (if that's your desired behaviour) multiple times.

```
function playSongOneFunction(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    songOne.play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far and that solves my problem for the sound to play everytime you roll over. But I was wondering if there was a way to only allow it to play once at a time? So it would only start again when the sound stopped.

Comment: If you only want it to play once, then the boolean solution that you have above should be good; you just need to reset the `soundPlaying` bool. Add a sound complete listener and reset it there (though add the listener outside of the `PlaySongOneFunction`, otherwise you'll add a new one every time)